# Uploading Video using http post request android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, chunks

I need to upload a video to server using http service call.

For that I have a service call as below.

http://capmem.omsoftware.co/Event/UploadVideo?callback=localJsonpCallback&chunk=&totalSize=&Filename=&UserID=&EventID=&comment=&VideoLength=

How can I get chunk of bytes to pass in "chunk" parameter in the service call.?

Here is my code

```
int mychunkSize = 100 * 1024;


            realPath = getRealPathFromURI(videoFileUri);
            System.out.println("file name" + realPath);

            long size1 = realPath.length();
            size = Long.toString(size1);

            System.out.println("total size" + size);
            long chunks1 = size1 < mychunkSize ? 1
                    : (realPath.length() / mychunkSize);
            chunks = Long.toString(chunks1);
```

Is this the correct way to get chunk of bytes (chunks).?

Please help..

Comment: No. But what has videoLength to do with the calculation? And Long.toString(). Please remove all irrelevant code.

Comment: I removed all irrelevant code. Please have a look.

Comment: It looks like all System.out's and all Long.toStings are irrelevant too. Please remove. They confuse me.

Comment: If realPath is of type String and is indeed the name of the file then realPath.length() is the length of that string. I think you want something to calculate starting with the file length. So you have to determine the real length first.

Answer (score 2):

use multipart to upload

[Uploading large files from android to c# WCF Rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912980/uploading-large-files-from-android-to-c-sharp-wcf-rest-service)

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("FileData", new FileBody(file));


            httppost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I showed you my code, the chunk data passing is correct way or not.?